# Is it possible in a single tableview, first 3 cells data is static and the rest of the tablecell data is dynamic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I m currently stucked over this ! Can anyone plz suggest me to over come this?

I have a `UITableView` with dynamic number of rows.
Tableview contents are >
i. `Imageview`
ii. `Title1`
iii. `Title2`

Requirement is > for the first 3 `cells`, data (`imagview`, `title1`, `title2`) are static. Let's say to feed from `array` (`imgarr`, `title1arr`, `title2arr`).

But the rest of the cell data need to be dynamic which is coming from webserivice.
I am fully confused how to feed data from index 3 onwards. (index0,index1, index2 data are coming from array)!

Comment: Yes It is possible, Take array and add first static data and after add dynamic darta. and reload your table view.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't have a table view that is both static and dynamic, at least not the way that Apple defines a static table view (where the table view controller feeds the contents for a fixed set of cells and you don't have to implement the data source methods.

However, you CAN set up your data source so it is populated with 3 fixed items for the first 3 rows and then data that's loaded from a webservice. That seems pretty simple to me.

You could either define a mutable array that you seed with the first 3 items and then populate the rest from the webservice, or write your data source methods so that you supply the first 3 items from one (immutable) array and all the rest from a mutable array that you populate from the webservice.

Comment: hi Duncan,thanks for ur answer. 
But i applied that. but not getting the all value. For first 3 cells, ok. but the rests are not populating data as per my expectation.SO can u please suggest with logic or coding?

Comment: It's all but impossible to "suggest with logic or coding" to fix the code in your program. When the number of cells in your table view changes because new data arrives from your webservice, you need to call the table view's reloadData method to get it to display the new contents.

Comment: I could write code that does what you ask, but it would be a fair amount of work for me, and it wouldn't fit into your app anyway.

Answer (score -1):

In `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, return specific height for the first 3 cells and  `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the rest cells.